# "Retadreso" or "retpoŝtadreso" for "e-mail address"?

Tags: word-choice

I just signed up at Libera Folio and it asked for my *retadreso* and I typed the URL to my YouTube account. It gave an error and I then realized that it wanted my e-mail address.

I learned *retpoŝtadreso* for *e-mail address*. I have been under the (apparently wrong) impression that *retadreso* meant URL.

Which one should I use? Does *retadreso* always, in all cases, mean *e-mail address*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have been under the (apparently wrong) impression that retadreso meant URL.

No, your impression is not apparently wrong. Retadreso does mean URL but often retpoŝtadreso is shortened to retadreso, which IMHO is a bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

For *e-mail address*, PIV gives the simpler word *retadreso* (which is, however, used for *web address*), while other sources prefer the unambiguous *retpoŝtadreso*. As usual, this info comes from [Komputeko.net](http://komputeko.net/index_eo.php).

And I see you have already been given the translation of *URL*:
[Kiel oni diras "URL" esperante?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1349/kiel-oni-diras-url-esperante)