# Kiel oni diras "URL" esperante?

Tags: single-word-requests

Ekzemple:

> *Kio estas la _____________ de via retejo?*

Plenigu la spacon.

*Retadreso*?
*Ligoadreso*?
Ĉu ekzistas alia pli ĝusta elekto?

Comment: Since the question already makes clear its is asking about a network, you could just say _adreso_.

Comment: Maybe the sentence I used is a bad example. I'm just wanting to know the most common and correct word to refer to the "internet address" or "URL" of a website.

Comment: I apologize: I didn't mean the example was bad. I just meant that in that specific case, there should be the need of specify of which address you are talking of, but generally speaking you indeed use a more specific word than _adreso_,

Comment: No need to apologize :) I see what you mean. Sometimes in English I might say "What's your website's URL?" which is why I used that sentence.

Comment: Sigh! It was supposed to be "there should not be the need of specifying which address you are talking of."

Comment: Actually, that use of URL is not right to start with. URL locates (by definition) a single resource, like a particular question here, not a website as a whole. The address `www.something.com` translates to an actual URL, like `https://www.something.com/index.html`, even though this may happen internally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Komputeko](http://komputeko.net/index_eo.php?vorto=url), the phrase is *reteja adreso* or *unuforma risurca lokindiko*. So I think in your example it would make sense to write *reteja adreso*, however I think normally people just say *adreso* and it is clear from the context what they are talking about.

I hear *retadreso* a lot to refer to an email address so I think that usage is pretty much standardised, even if it seems a little strange.

Comment: I think _retadreso_ is shortened from _retpoŝtadreso_ or _retpoŝta adreso_. Why such a strange form has spread, one explanation could be in, how should I put this diplomatically, a rather senior-leaning age structure in many Esperanto organisations.

Answer (score 7):

Mi preferas uzi ne tiel laŭvortan frazon: *Kio estas la ligilo al via retejo*.

Comment: Mi ankaux preskaux cxiam vidas "ligilo" en Telegramo pri tio.

Answer (score 6):

Vi ja povas diri URL, prononcata /u.ro.lo/ aŭ /u.ʁo.lo/, kiu bone kongruas kun la esperanta [Unuforma Rimeda Lokindiko](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL).